# Автоматическое создание форм jquery

Tags: jquery, форма

Возможно есть уже готовые плагины для автоматического создания своих форм с помощью jquery по типу как это делаеться у ext js ?
Т.е. указал что нужно в форме, где она должна быть и скрипт ее сам сделал, что то типа такого в ext js:

```
    var ActPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
        frame: true,
        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            id: 'siteaddr',
            fieldLabel: 'Адрес сайта',
            name: 'siteaddr',
            allowBlank:false,
            anchor: '100%'
        },
...
```

Классно получаеться, к кнопачкам привязуеться ajax, формочки эти можно свободно перемещать куда угодно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, я вот этим пользовался: [jQuery form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). Или просто $.ajax и самому отправлять.

Еще есть [виджет](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) формы, но лучше нарисовать свою с любым дизайном.